# Can't open file dialog using Electron and Angular

Tags: angularjs, electron

I cannot figure out how to show the open file dialog from Electron.

When I use the provided example I get an error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'electron' from '/Users/michaelcalkins/Code/codesketcher/assets/js'`

https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md

I'm using browserify to build the app anything I try just generates errors.

Gulpfile contents:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir')
elixir.config.assetsPath = 'assets'

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss', 'dist/css')
       .browserify('app.js', 'dist/js')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the way that you transpile with gulp is important.  For whatever reason Laravel Elixir breaks the build.  Using a different gulpfile I was able to make it work perfectly.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    run = require('gulp-run'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    del = require('del')

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('./assets/js/app.js')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(rename('index.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
})

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return sass('assets/sass/app.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }))
})

gulp.task('run', ['default'], function() {
    return run('electron .').exec()
})

gulp.task('watch', ['scripts', 'styles'], function (cb) {
    watch('assets/js/**/*.js', function () {
        gulp.run('scripts')
    })

    watch('assets/scss/**/*.scss', function () {
        gulp.run('styles')
    })
})

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles'])
```